# How do I correlate the Rayleigh-Taylor instability with this Marangoni Bursting phenomenon?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, density, surface-tension, evaporation

The droplet was a water-isopropanol mixture of concentration 50% and was deposited on a 5mm thick layer of sunflower oil in a petri dish.[image]

Comment: I've read that the sizes of the droplets left behind by the droplet are related to the Rayleigh-Taylor instability of liquid cylinders, but I am not sure how.